# mysql order by the same as a list that i have in a variable

Tags: mysql

I am pulling information that has cities attached to it and i would like the information to be in a order where it shows the current city first, then cities in an order by distance from the city searched.  I have the cities in the  order that i would want them shown in an array called $nearby_city_array.  Is there any way that I could pull the data, in order, according to where it shows up in my array?

```
$query = "SELECT
             username, city, state
        FROM
        ...
        WHERE
                      city = '" . $city . "'
              state = '" . $state . "'
            ORDER BY " . $nearby_city_array . ";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
```

Any ideas would be great thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you have found a better solution, i.e. one using the information stored in the database, someone else visiting this question might search for a solution for the original question.

This is the idea:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_order (cntup INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT, city VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO tmp_order (city) VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ... -- this is the order
SELECT <fields> FROM mytable JOIN tmp_order USING (city) ORDER BY cntup
```

This creates a temporary table containing the data in the order as they are in the list. If you join this table to your original query and order the result by the row ID in the temp table, you get exactly what you want.

As said, if you can omit this list and use data which are already present in the DB, it is better.

Comment: cool that looks like what i was initially looking for.  thanks

Comment: @noWayhome But your own solution is better, as it is easier and you don't have to issue several SQL queries.

Comment: Its things like this that separates average sql code from good sql... well done

Answer (score 1):

You need a numerical distance for each, limit the results, sort it by the city and order it so that your selected city is the first in the list.

Comment: so is there no way to do it by comparing it to a list that i already have?

Comment: you can't sort a list by distance if you dont have the distances handy to compare. So, if your nearby city array contains something other than city names, then yes. otherwise, you'd need to know some kind of number to specify how and why they are "nearby".

Comment: the nearby city array that i have is already sorted by distance i used the lat and long in a previous mysql statement to populate the array.

Comment: oh, i see. You know, thats a good question. :) now i'm not sure, couldn't you just combine queries so that way you do have those numbers handy?

Answer (score 1):

The `ORDER BY` Clause must be followed by name(s) of the `column` or `Field` and not record(s) of nearby_city.

Answer (score 1):

ended up doing this and it works fine.

```
$mylat = mylatitude 

$mylon = mylongitude

$query = "SELECT
            city, state, latitude, longitude,
         3959 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((".$mylat." - abs(f.latitude)) * pi()/180/2), 2) + COS(f.latitude * pi()/180) * COS(abs(f.latitude) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((".$mylon." - f.longitude) * pi()/180 /2), 2) )) AS `distance` 
  FROM 
  ...
  WHERE
    c.posted = 'posted' AND     
    f.city  IN($nearby_city_string) AND                     
    f.state IN($nearby_state_string
    ORDER BY `distance` ASC,  date DESC LIMIT 0, 30";

$result_nearby = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
```